# Get TypeInfo in static constructor

Tags: static, constructor, typeinfo

Is there any way to get the equivalent of GetType within a static constructor?

I want to iterate through the available properties of the type within the static constructor but GetType is an instance method?  Why is this?  The typeinfo should exist in the static context.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
Type type = typeof(TheCurrentType);
```

It should never be more complex than this since you always know the actual type; there's no polymorphism to deal with in static methods.

Comment: But I have to know the runtime type. I want to register all the runtime-types (at runtime) that inherits from this class, I have to walk thru all its attributes and properties and register them in a custom engine, this has to be done once per type during the app lifetime, and for each subclass, is there a way to resolve the runtime type?

Comment: @Shimmy there's no polymorphism in static methods. The static method belongs to the type it's declared to, regardless of any derived types.

Comment: I decided to create a simple protected static method RegisterMetadata(Type type) on the base type to be called from its subclasses. The thing is there is no way to enforce the calling of this method from all its subclasses' static ctor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get derived types (other than by iterating through all types to see what derives from the current type). To get the current type, you can:

```
Type currentType = (new StackFrame()).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
```